# What is the meaning of 'being drawn to someone'

Tags: meaning

I think 'drawn' means  'showing the wearing effects of overwork, care or suffering', but I can't understand what 'you are drawn to her' will be meaning right here.

Comment: In this case, *drawn* is not an adjective, but the past participle of the verb *[to draw](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/draw)*, here probably meaning *Gently pull or guide (someone) in a specified direction*. This question, incidentally, may be more suitable for our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should provide SOME context.  But in the usual use of the phrase "drawn to X", "drawn" means "attracted".

Comment: being drawn to someone most likely means in love with someone.

Comment: (A) I agree with the first part of choster's comment. (B) You say you don't understand what it means 'right here'.  Right where? You haven't given us the context.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "to be drawn to a person" means "to be attracted to a person". This does not necessarily mean sexually or romantically, but it is often used that way.

You may be thinking of "drawn" in the artistic sense, as in making a sketch, but that would be phrased as "you are drawn by her". It is also possible to use "drawn" in the sense of "attracted" with "by", as in the sentence, "He was drawn by her passionate denunciation of the political corruption."

EDIT - Per Catija's comment, if the adjectival form of drawn was intended, it would probably be in the form of "You looked (or appeared) drawn to her." The past tense would be used, since the speaker would presumably be passing on the results of a conversation with "her", since there would be no other way to know how she interpreted your appearance.

Comment: I don't think the OP thinks it means the artistic sense... I think he's guessing at [this definition](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/drawn_2) instead of [definition six](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/draw_1).

Answer (score 1):

*to be drawn* is simply the passive form of *to draw* meaning *to pull* or *to attract*.

Active: John drew the phone towards him.

Passive: The phone was drawn towards John (by John).

Active: John was so good-looking that he drew all the women towards him as if by magnetism.  (John attracted the women)

Passive: John was so good-looking that all the women were drawn towards him as if by magnetism. (the women were attracted by John)

If you are drawn to someone, it means they have a quality that draws (pulls/attracts) you to them.

Answer (score 0):

Being drawn to someone means you are  attracted to them but it doesn't have to be sexual it can but also it can mean their good behavior attracts you.

Answer (score 0):

In this sense it means to attract, however, that is not necessarily a romantic or sexual feeling. In this context the word drawn means to get the viewer's attention in such a way that they focus on the subject more than just simply noticing them, in addition, this is saying that the person that is being drawn has greater interest in the subject.